# How can I subscribe to two different observables that come from paramMap?

Tags: angular, rxjs

When I am requesting data using route params `paramMap` I'm able to get everything working great when it's a single argument. For example, `foo.getThing(id)`.

I am struggling how to "observe" multiple arguments though. I need both, my `organizationId` *and* my `locationId` to look up a location.

I've been reading through several tutorials and perhaps ForkJoin may be what I need, but all I have seen so far is getting the initial request from something that doesn't take arguments. For example, `foo.getStuff()` not `foo.getThing(id)`

```
// settings.component.ts

private organizationId!: string;
private locationId!: string;

private organizationId$ = this.activatedRoute.paramMap.pipe(
    tap((params) => {
        this.organizationId = params.get('organizationId')!;
    })
);

private locationId$ = this.activatedRoute.paramMap.pipe(
    tap((params) => {
        this.locationId = params.get('locationId')!;
    })
);

public location$: Observable<ILocation> = this.locationId$.pipe(
    switchMap(() =>
        this.locationService.getLocation(this.organizationId, this.locationId)
    )
);
```

When I am getting details about my organization, I can just subscribe to the `organizationId`. If that changes, the response updates accordingly.

I am trying to accomplish the same for my location. If the `organizationId` *or* `locationId` change, I'd like the pipe to re-run and get the correct data.

How can I subscribe to two different observables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not "*How can I subscribe to two different observables?*", but rather, "*How can I create an observable from multiple sources, that emits whenever any of the sources emit*".

ginalx is right, [`combineLatest`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/combinelatest) will help you with this:

```js
  private organizationId$ = this.activatedRoute.paramMap.pipe(
    map(params => params.get('organizationId')),
    distinctUntilChanged()
  );

  private locationId$ = this.activatedRoute.paramMap.pipe(
    map(params => params.get('locationId')),
    distinctUntilChanged()
  );

  public location$ = combineLatest([this.organizationId$, this.locationId$]).pipe(
    switchMap(([orgId, locId]) => this.locationService.getLocation(orgId, locId))
  );
```

---

However, if your only sources both come the route params, it may be simpler to use `params` instead of `paramMap` since you have access to the full params object (*not just a single value*):

```js
  public location$ = this.activatedRoute.params.pipe(
    switchMap(params => this.locationService.getLocation(params.organizationId, params.locationId))
  );
```

Comment: I really appreciate all of the insight you provide. Changing from a procedural mindset to a declarative is tricky! Not to mention trying to get a grasp of observables/rxjs. Thank you for all of your patience & grace. I would really like to buy you a coffee or something. You can find me `@damonjentree`

Answer (score 3):

My good!! "make it simple, make it easy" (*)

```
//if we want to store the params in this.organizationID and this.locationId 
location$=this.activatedRoute.paramMap.pipe(
          switchMap(params=>{
             this.organizationId = params.get('organizationId')!
             this.locationId = params.get('locationId')!
             return this.locationService.getLocation(this.organizationId, this.locationId)
          }))
```

Or

```
//if we needn't store the params
location$=this.activatedRoute.paramMap.pipe(
          switchMap(params=>{
             const organizationId = params.get('organizationId')!
             const locationId = params.get('locationId')!
             return this.locationService.getLocation(organizationId, locationId)
          }))
```

(*) Why all the another answers are so complex?

Comment:  Great question! I hadn't thought about that! `paramMap` is _already_ a combined observable!

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is probably `combineLatest`. Adding `distinctUntilChanged` because it should fit your case

```js
private organizationId$ = this.activatedRoute.paramMap.pipe(
    map((params) => params.get('organizationId')),
    distinctUntilChanged()
);

private locationId$ = this.activatedRoute.paramMap.pipe(
    map((params) => params.get('locationId')),
    distinctUntilChanged()
);

private whatYouNeed$ = combineLatest([this.organizationId$, this.locationId$])
```

One way to get the values is this for example

```js
this.whatYouNeed$.subscribe(([organizationId, locationId]) => console.log(organizationId, locationId))
```

Comment: Is `combineLatest` deprecated? [One page](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/combineLatest) says yes, [another](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/combineLatest) says no.

Comment: @JSmart523 There are two different `combineLatest`: one is a [static function](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/combineLatest) which is not deprecated, the other is a pipeable [operator](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/combineLatest) which has been renamed to [`combineLatestFrom`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/combineLatestWith)

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH for your help! Reading through this was a tremendous help not only figuring out what I should do, but *what* to research.

Answer (score 1):

[combineLatestWith](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/combineLatestWith) is an operator combines the source with provided observables to emit an array of each observable's latest values each time any of them changes. So you'd want to change your `location$` definition to:

```js
const location$ = locationId$.pipe(
  combineLatestWith(organizationId$),
  switchMap(
    ([locId, orgId]) =>
    this.locationService.getLocation(
      locId,
      orgId
    )
  )
);
```